# Get word that is surrounded by [tag] in brackets[/tag]

Tags: php, regex

I would like to get a list of words, that is surrounded by a BBCode-like "tag".

E.g.:

```
$string = "Hello [tag]world[/tag], how [notag]are[/notag] you today? I am [tag]fine[/tag].";
```

This should return an array like this:

- world
- fine

because both are surrounded by [tag], but "are" should not be added, because it is surrounded by another tag.

At the moment I try to check and replace the findings this way:

```
$e->innertext = preg_replace(
                                '/\b' . preg_quote( "[tag]".$text."[/tag]", "/" ) . '\b/i',
                                "<a href='$url'>\$0</a>",
                                $e->innertext,
                                1
                            );
```

Comment: Please include your coding attempt.

Comment: Does `[tag]` refer to a _specific_ tag?

Comment: Possible Dup of [PHP Regex Get Text Between BBCode Tags](//stackoverflow.com/q/9640670), [RegEx: Get the code between a BB \[code\] tag](//stackoverflow.com/q/28446446), [Using a regular expression to extract text in between BBCode-style tags](//stackoverflow.com/q/9331041), [Regex / BBCode Parser to find string between two strings (Between two strings) and replace it](//stackoverflow.com/q/23522022)

Comment: Hello there, I updated my post with my attempt to replace it automatically for every finding.

Answer (score 2):

This should work -

```
preg_match_all('/\[tag\](.*?)\[\/tag\]/', $string, $match);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [tag]world[/tag]
            [1] => [tag]fine[/tag]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => world
            [1] => fine
        )

)
```

[Code](https://eval.in/813399)

Answer (score 1):

Using lookbehind and lookahead, you can avoid capture groups.

Code ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2a553848a6a2fc866bbcf1f8b249a9d0bc21f603)):

```
$string = "Hello [tag]world[/tag], how [notag]are[/notag] you today? I am [tag]fine[/tag].";
var_export(preg_match_all('/(?<=\[tag\])[^[]+(?=\[\/tag\])/',$string,$out)?$out[0]:[]);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'world',
  1 => 'fine',
)
```

---

Or for pattern speed (faster than Sougata's pattern), use capture group with negated character class ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pved3j/3)):

```
$string = "Hello [tag]world[/tag], how [notag]are[/notag] you today? I am [tag]fine[/tag].";
var_export(preg_match_all('/\[tag\]([^[]+)\[\/tag\]/',$string,$out)?$out[1]:[]);
```

Comment: yeah, typo, got it thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also get by try this code..

```
<?php
 $string = "Hello [tag]world[/tag], how [notag]are[/notag] you today? I am [tag]fine[/tag].";
 $s2 = explode('[tag]', $string);
 $s3 = array();
 foreach($s2 as $val){
 if (strpos($val, '[/tag]') !== false) {
   $s3[] = explode('[/tag]', $val)[0];
  }
}
echo '<pre>'; print_r($s3);
```

?>

Comment: Why not, but if tags aren't balanced like this: `abcd[/tag] efgh [tag]ijkl`, your code will return `abcd`. However regex answers are not perfect too.